# Issue with loop in Bicep for vNet peering

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I'm looking to implement a data driven approach for my vNet peers whereby I can simply add in additional peers just through adding to the parameter file

Here is my bicep

```
param peers object


resource sourcevNet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-03-01' existing = {
  name: peers.vNetPeeringSourceNetwork
}

resource vNetPeer 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings@2020-05-01' = [ for j in range(0, length(peers.peerings)): { 
  parent: sourcevNet
  name: '${peers.vNetPeeringSourceNetwork}-${peers.peerings[j]}'
  properties: [ for i in range(0, length(peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork)): {
    allowVirtualNetworkAccess: peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].allowVirtualNetworkAccess
    allowForwardedTraffic: peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].allowForwardedTraffic
    allowGatewayTransit: peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].allowGatewayTransit
    useRemoteGateways: peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].useRemoteGateways
    remoteVirtualNetwork:  {
      id: peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].remote == false ? resourceId('${peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].peeredNetworkResourceGroup}','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', '${peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].peerNetworkSuffix}') : resourceId('${peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].remoteNetworkSubscription}','${peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].peeredNetworkResourceGroup}','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', '${peers.peerings[j].vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork[i].peerNetworkSuffix}')
    }
  }]
}]
```

and here is the parameters

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": 
    {
    "peers": {
      "value":{
        "peerings":[
          {
        "vNetPeeringSourceNetwork": "Test-VM2",
        "vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork": [
          {
                "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
                "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
                "allowGatewayTransit": false,
                "useRemoteGateways": false,
                "remote": false,
                "peerNetworkSuffix": "TestVM-vnet",
                "peeredNetworkResourceGroup": "TestVM",
                "remoteNetworkSubscription": "37beac69-e9c7-40fc-9d7b-6c1adf274185"
          },
          {
            "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
            "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
            "allowGatewayTransit": false,
            "useRemoteGateways": false,
            "remote": false,
            "peerNetworkSuffix": "TestVM-vnet3",
            "peeredNetworkResourceGroup": "TestVM",
            "remoteNetworkSubscription": "37beac69-e9c7-40fc-9d7b-6c1adf274185"
      }   
          ]
        }
        ]
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

For some reason it doesn't like the 2nd loop for properties.

VSCode gives this
The property "properties" expected a value of type "VirtualNetworkPeeringPropertiesFormat | null" but the provided value is of type "object[]". If this is an inaccuracy in the documentation, please report it to the Bicep Team.bicephttps://aka.ms/bicep-type-issues

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `properties` attribute on the `vNetPeer` resource should be an object but you are passing an array (because of the loop).

Nested loop are not yet supported (see [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/1280)).

In you case, you could wrap the creation of the resources inside a module.

Also in your ARM parameters file, you could use an array directly so you don't have to do `peers.peerings`

**parameters.json** file:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "peerings": {
      "value": [
        {
          "vNetPeeringSourceNetwork": "Test-VM2",
          "vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork": [
            {
              "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
              "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
              "allowGatewayTransit": false,
              "useRemoteGateways": false,
              "remote": false,
              "peerNetworkSuffix": "TestVM-vnet",
              "peeredNetworkResourceGroup": "TestVM",
              "remoteNetworkSubscription": "37beac69-e9c7-40fc-9d7b-6c1adf274185"
            },
            {
              "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
              "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
              "allowGatewayTransit": false,
              "useRemoteGateways": false,
              "remote": false,
              "peerNetworkSuffix": "TestVM-vnet3",
              "peeredNetworkResourceGroup": "TestVM",
              "remoteNetworkSubscription": "37beac69-e9c7-40fc-9d7b-6c1adf274185"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**vnet-peering.bicep** module:

```bicep
param peering object

resource sourcevNet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-03-01' existing = {
  name: peering.vNetPeeringSourceNetwork
}

resource vNetPeer 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings@2020-05-01' = [for destination in peering.vNetPeeringDestinationNetwork: {
  parent: sourcevNet
  name: '${peering.vNetPeeringSourceNetwork}-${destination.peerNetworkSuffix}'
  properties: {
    allowVirtualNetworkAccess: destination.allowVirtualNetworkAccess
    allowForwardedTraffic: destination.allowForwardedTraffic
    allowGatewayTransit: destination.allowGatewayTransit
    useRemoteGateways: destination.useRemoteGateways
    remoteVirtualNetwork: {
      id: destination.remote == false ? resourceId(destination.peeredNetworkResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', destination.peerNetworkSuffix) : resourceId(destination.remoteNetworkSubscription, destination.peeredNetworkResourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', destination.peerNetworkSuffix)
    }
  }
}]
```

And **main.bicep** template:

```bicep
param peerings array

module vnetPeerings 'vnet-peering.bicep' = [for (peering, i) in peerings: {
  name: 'vnet-peering-${i}'
  params: {
    peering: peering
  }
}]
```